# Displaying DFP ads on iOS using GoogleMobileAds.framework

Tags: ios, swift

I’m trying to display DFP ads using GoogleMobileAds framework.

Code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: DFPBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let request = DFPRequest()
        request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]

        bannerView.delegate = self
        bannerView.adUnitID = "/6499/example/banner"
//        bannerView.adUnitID = “/my_network/my_unit_id”
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.loadRequest(request)
    }
```

It works fine with the Google test ad unit ID and setting testDevices.

With my own ad unit ID, I still get the test banner, not my own. 
If I comment out the “testDevices” line, I get the following error, and no banner: “ To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];”, with both the test ad unit ID and my own ad unit ID.

The same issue happens on the device, using the correct device ID instead of kGADSimulatorID.
Is there something else that needs configuring before displaying DFP ads ? How can I get the app to correctly display the ads ?

**Later Edit:**

I can get ads now, same code as above, if I set the size of the banner view to the specific size of the ad unit (300x250):

```
let bannerView = DFPBannerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 250))
```

However, any other size will result in didFailToReceiveAdWithError delegate method being called, with the error “Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show.””

```
let bannerView = DFPBannerView(adSize:kGADAdSizeBanner)
```

results in the same error.

I need to show ads that can resize to the full width of the device, from 320 to 414 (6 Plus). Is there any way to do it other than adding the resolutions to the ad unit ?

Answer (score 0):

The error..

> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[
>   kGADSimulatorID ];

Is not actually an error, it's just advice.

When you run with the test devices registered, it obviously shows the test unit to show that the library is loaded and working as expected.

When you remove the test devices and also change the ad unit ID to your own then as long as the following have been done then it should work:

1. in DFP, Under the Inventory tab. Have you created a ad unit such as My_Test_ad
2. When you create this ad unit have you enabled adSense ads and connected an AdExchane to your DFP account?
3. You should also be able to run delivery diagnostics to ensure that the ad unit is working properly and serving ads.

If all the above have been done then you should be getting ad units. I would guess that the adExchange part has not been setup and therefore you have no ads to show.

I can't remember them specifically but there are delegate functions to the library that can tell you when an error occurred, a fetch failed or succeeded, try adding these and logging some information into the console to see what is happening.